# Spring Batch job description missing in the JobBuilderFactory

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

In the Spring Batch job XML configuration there was the possibility to add a job description

```
<xsd:element name="job">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="description" type="description" minOccurs="0"/>
            ...
        </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:element>
```

Questions:

1. Why is this not possible anymore in the Java configuration?
2. Spring Batch Admin has a column called Description, but it doesn't show anything.

As far as I can tell from the source code of both Spring Batch and Admin this is never stored/retrieved from the job repository. What is the reason behind it?